# Two questions about the architecture of Google Bert model (in particular about parameters)

Tags: natural-language-processing, bert

I'm looking for someone who can help me clarify a few details regarding the architecture of Bert model. Those details are necessary for me to come with a full understanding of Bert model, so your help would be really helpful. Here are the questions:

- Does the self-attention layer of Bert model have parameters? Do the embeddings of words change ONLY according to the actual embeddings of other words when the sentence is passed through the self-attention layer?
- Are the parameters of the embedding layer of the model (the layer which transforms the sequence of indexes passed as input into a sequence of embeddings of size=size of the model) trainable or not?